# Sorting on Templated Column with converters

Tags: wpf, xaml, sorting, mvvm, datagrid

My datamodel is like this:

```
    public class ModelA
    {
    public int ModelId{get;set;}
    }
    public class ModelB
    {
      public IEnumerable<ModelA> ChildObjects{get;set;}
    }
```

Now in the Xaml, am using a DataGrid with the ItemSource as List(), and have a template column which binds to ChildObjects with a converter doing the job of getting the first element from ChildObjects and returning the value as that object's ModelId. Now all works fine till now. The issue is when I do sorting on this templated column.

I know one workaround is to have an extra property in ModelB which does the job of what converter is doing and make the sortmemberpath in xaml as that new property name, but that is not what I want as its against the model.

Is there any other perfect way to handle this scenario, as the SortMemberPath can't be made as expression as its just a contant.

Answer (score 0):

You've tagged this MVVM, which I assume means your models are actually view models (or are at least wrapped by view models). That being the case, why *wouldn't* you add the extra property? After all, it's there to support the view. Your view needs the extra property, so your view model should provide it.

Comment: My View model is like SampleViewModel with the property - BoundItems which is List<ModelB>, In the template column am binding to this property with each row corresponding to one ModelB object, the converter in template column is taking out the first object of ModelA from the ChildObjectList property of modelB and bindng the ModelId of ModelA object to that column. Now if I want to do the logic, I need to do on the Model, not ViewModel....

Comment: Right - you're binding to model objects instead of wrapping them in view models first. That's the crux of your problem and is what you need to fix.